# Mobile SDK, XCode 6 XIB and Storyboards

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

When you create a new project in XCode 6.* using the  SF Mobile SDK, there is no option to use Storyboards, XCode 's version of XIB files.
I want to work with Storyboards but not with XIB files.
is there a way around this deadlock ?
Thanks

Comment: That's just a project template to populate a new app with the mobile SDK. You can add storyboards to your app at any time after creating the project. Also it is not accurate to say "Storyboards, Xcode's version of XIB files". They are two separate things, both part of Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Jonathan's comment above, you can look at [this](https://github.com/VignetteInteractive/Salesforce-template) sample project which hooks up an older version of the Mobile SDK to Storyboards.

The bottom line though - the mobile SDK provides you a template code structure to work off and you can remove the XIB dependencies and introduce the storyboard. To know more about that, read [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/index.html).